# Why does eclipse generate, "Unable to find/resolve artifact. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:unpack:unpack:package)" error?

Tags: java, maven, docker, spring-boot

I am trying to follow the spring-boot tutorial for docker (https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/).  I want to follow the maven build example in the tutorial.  I am using Eclipse Oxygen, which comes with maven (M2Eclipse) and I also Apache Maven 3.5.3 installed on my machine.

After I run,

```
mvn install dockerfile:build
```

from the command line, I switch back to eclipse and see an error in the pom file.
Why is this occurring?  Is there any way to fix it?

The error message shown in eclipse when viewing the pom file:

```
Unable to find/resolve artifact. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:unpack:unpack:package)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to find/resolve artifact.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.getProcessedArtifactItems(UnpackMojo.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo.doExecute(UnpackMojo.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.AbstractDependencyMojo.execute(AbstractDependencyMojo.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.core.MdpBuildParticipant.executeMojo(MdpBuildParticipant.java:133)
    at com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.core.MdpBuildParticipant.build(MdpBuildParticipant.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.ArtifactResolverException: Failure to find org.springframework:gs-spring-boot-docker:jar:0.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.getArtifact(AbstractFromConfigurationMojo.java:248)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.springframework:gs-spring-boot-docker:jar:0.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.resolve.internal.Maven31ArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(Maven31ArtifactResolver.java:108)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.springframework:gs-spring-boot-docker:jar:0.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: It might be because of your Maven Setup. Follow the Maven Troubleshooting Guide and see if it helps.

Comment: maybe because you ran `mvn install dockerfile:build` instead of the maven wrapper `mvnw install dockerfile:build`
Just give it a try?

Comment: @Shreyas, mvnw is the Maven wrapper. This allows one to run the Maven project without having Maven installed and present on the path. I already have maven installed locally on my machine and I am also using eclipse ide with e2m.  The problem is that eclipse is seeing the pom as invalid.

Comment: what is the complaint given by the eclipse for `pom.xml`?
did you try `Maven` -> `Update Project`?

Comment: The complain is in my post above.  The long exception.  I have tried to maven update project

Comment: I deleted the pom and created it from scratch again with no copy and paste.  I am on a mac, so maybe there was an issue with the file.  Then did a clean and then update project.  Then I used m2e to create the maven build.  No errors.  I don't know what fixed it.  No idea

Comment: ohh okk..
glad it worked out('on its own', but am still curious how it worked out 'on its own')
because there has to be some reason.